# extract image from image

Tags: java, jpeg, ocr, libraries

Is it possible to extract an image from a jpeg, png or tiff file? NOT PDF! Suppose I have a file containing both text and images in jpeg format (so it's basically a picture); I want to be able to extract the image only programmatically (preferably using Java). If anyone knows useful libraries please let me know. I have already tried AspriseOCR and tesseract-ocr, they have been successful at extracting text only (obviously).
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have some code? Or are you looking for ideas?

Comment: I used Xuggler for images and video treatment.

Comment: I am looking for ideas. Libraries I could use. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
int startProintX  = xxx;
int startProintY  = xxx;
int endProintX  = xxx;
int endProintY  = xxx;
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/temp/test.jpg"));   
BufferedImage out = image.getSubimage(startProintX, startProintY, endProintX, endProintY);
ImageIO.write(out, "jpg", new File("D:/temp/result.jpg"));
```

These point are region of image you want to extract.

**Extract image from pdf file**

I suggest to change your post tile. You can use `pdfbox` or `iText` api. The below example to extract the all of the image from pdf file.
There might be some resource for you. If there are a lot of image in pdf, may be occur `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

Download `pdfbox.xx.jar` [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpdfbox180jar.htm).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.pdfbox.PDFBox;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectImage;
import org.jdom.Document;

public class ExtractImagesFromPDF {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("D:/temp/test.pdf"));
         List pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
         Iterator iter = pages.iterator();
         while(iter.hasNext()) {
             PDPage page = (PDPage)iter.next();
             PDResources resources = page.getResources();
             Map images = resources.getImages();
             if( images != null ) {
                 Iterator imageIter = images.keySet().iterator();
                 while(imageIter.hasNext()) {
                     String key = (String)imageIter.next();
                     System.out.println("Key : " + key);
                     PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage)images.get(key);
                     File file = new File("D:/temp/" +  key + "." + image.getSuffix());
                     image.write2file(file);
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

**Extract specific image from pdf file**

To extract specific image, you have to know `index of page` and `index of image` of that page. Otherwise, you cannot extract.

The following example program extract `first image` of `first page`.

```
 int targetPage = 0;
 PDPage firstPage = (PDPage)document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(targetPage);
 PDResources resources = firstPage.getResources();
 Map images = resources.getImages();
 int targetImage = 0;
 String imageKey = "Im" + targetImage; 
 PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage)images.get(imageKey);
 File file = new File("D:/temp/" +  imageKey + "." + image.getSuffix());
 image.write2file(file);
```

Comment: Thanks, that kind of helps. How would I go about if the coordinates of the image are not known? @CycDemo

Comment: @iAmIronMan :), I am not sure, you have to know `coordinates point` region to extract. If so try and try again to meet your target.

Comment: I tried it out and it's pretty helpful actually :) However the program I am trying to write needs to able to detect those coordinates on its own, as the input file will vary. I have been able to detect image coordinates before but it was on a pdf file, not jpeg. Do you know of anything else that could be helpful to my situation? Thanks!

Comment: the file format I am dealing with is not pdf. It is an image file format (jpeg, png, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in an out-of-box product that could do this via black-box processing with minimal non-programming configuration (since you tried other products), then ABBYY FlexiCapture can do it.  It can be configured to look for dynamic sizes of pictures/objects in loosely defined areas, or anywhere on the page, with full control over search logic.  I used it once to extract lines of specific shape and thickness to separate chapters of a book, where each line indicated a new chapter, and could be anywhere on the page.